# Is it possible to concatenate all haarcascade *.xml into one file?

Tags: opencv

Is it possible to concatenate all haarcascade *.xml into one file ? I'd like to search faces in all possible situations.
If so, how to do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, Haar cascades process objects in coarse to fine order i.e. in the begining it uses only very simple and fast features to filter out hypothesis with very lo probability, next stage uses more complex features on smaller number of hypothesis with larger probabilities and so on. That's why I think you can't simply concatenate cascades. It's better use them separately. Or train your own.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible to concatenate them into one. But their results may be used in the same image for incresed accuracy. Import all of them in your code and detect features using all of them. But keep a check that the same feature is not detected multiple times. This can be easily done as we have the coordinates of each of the detected features.

Best of luck!